# How to protect IP-sensitive data in files generated and used by users

Tags: file-encryption, obfuscation

I'm working on an offline windows application that generates and loads key results as files. However, these files provide key insights into how our product works internally. To make matters worse my users will for sure be tech-savvy but not hacker like tech-savvy. So if I do not encode it, we give away our magic. So given this problem, I have some questions:

- Is there an encryption method commonly used to make files unreadable (or at least hard to read) except for (multiple instances of) a certain application?
- How hard is it to read what assets (like private keys) are baked into a .dll file?

Comment: Anything you give to your users can be deconstructed by your users. You need to re-think the core issue. Why do these files give away so much? All logic should not be in files. And why is it such an issue that your logic is exposed?

Comment: and if 100% unreadability is not the goal, but make it not worth the effort. What encryption would you use?

Comment: Any encryption makes everything "unreadable". That's what it does. So, pick your favourite. However, encryption is reversible and keys can be grabbed from memory (or DLLs).